# How to create cancellable tasks in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm building a Python IDE, which needs to highlight all occurrences of the name under cursor (using [Jedi](http://jedi.readthedocs.io) library). The process of finding the occurrences can be quite slow.

In order to avoid freezing the GUI, I could run the search in another thread, but when the user moves quickly over several words, the background threads could pile up while working on now obsolete tasks. I would like to cancel the search for previous occurrences when user moves to new name.

Looks like killing a thread is complicated in Python. What are the other options for creating an easily cancellable background tasks in Python 3.4+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread cannot be stopped by another one. This is a OS limitation rather than a Python one. Only thing you can do is periodically inspect a variable and, if set, stop the thread itself (just return).

Moreover, threads in Python suffer from the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). This means that CPU intensive operations, when carried out in a separate thread, will still affect your main loop as only one thread per process can run at a time.

I'd recommend you to run the search in a separate process which you can easily cancel whenever you want.

What the guys of [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) are doing for example is wrapping Jedi in a [HTTP server](https://github.com/vheon/JediHTTP) which they can query in the background. If the user moves the cursor before the completion comes back, the IDE can simply drop the request.

Answer (score 3):

I think `concurrent.futures` is the answer.
You can create a Thread / Process pool, `submit` any callable, receive a `Future`, which you can `cancel` if needed.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: Nice one. How would you compare it to using a work queue in terms of usability, flexibility and how easy it is to use?

Comment: Bare in mind that `Future.cancel` works only for tasks which are not started yet. Tasks which are in progress will keep running in the background until done.

Comment: I would say it has little overhead and is extremely easy to use. Submitting, result retrieving, cancelling are all one-liners. Work queues are nice, but a bit of an overkill in this situation, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my personal favorites are work queues. If it's a one-time application you should take a look at [python rq](http://python-rq.org/). Extremely easy and fun to use. If you want to build something more "professional-grade" take a look at something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

You might also want to look at [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)